# Can HTC Thunderbolt's LTE not be turned off?

Tags: 4g, htc-thunderbolt

I'm going to buy a Thunderbolt and I've heard that you can't turn LTE off on it. Is that true? If so, is there any workarounds for it?

Comment: I don't believe a phone with no option of turning data off exists.

Comment: Hay just so you know this is a phone from 2011

Comment: @SarpSTA not to be mean but this phone is from 2011 - legacy flagship phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** This tip should no be used if you're afraid of access phone features not advise by your carrier**

How to toggle LTE on your thunderbolt (the hard way)
This solution will allow you to toggle LTE because those if us with LTE are experiencing horrible battery life. This method will allow you to turn off LTE use and scanning which has increased my battery life 4 fold (8+ hours on a fufull charge with regular use while not using an app for battery effiency)

1. Access your dialer
2. Enter the code "*#*#4636#*#*"
3. Select "phone information"
4. Scroll down to "set preferred network type"
5. Select 'EvDo only" or "CDMA only" it "CDMA auto"
   This will disable the LTE radio.

To reactivate LTE:

1. Steps 1-4
2. Select "LTE Mode"
3. Open the menu again and select "CDMA+LTE/EvDo auto"

thanks to [this forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-htc-thunderbolt/70282-how-turn-off-lte.html)